# Character after forward slash in strings dropped by IntelliJ Idea (12.1) Groovy (2.1.1)

Tags: string, groovy, junit, intellij-idea

I am writing tests in Groovy for my Java application, and facing a strange problem, which can be explained with the below lines of code. Instead of printing /hello/world, it prints /ello/orld.

```
// File MyClassTest.groovy
import org.junit.Test

class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    void fun(){
        println("/hello/world")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/ello/orld
```

When I write a separate hello.groovy within the same project in IntelliJ IDEA, it prints /hello/world without any problem.

```
// File hello.groovy
println("/hello/world")
```

Output:

```
/hello/world
```

I am not providing any VM arguments in either case.

Anyone have any idea why this can happen?

Comment: Idea sometimes cut output in the wrong place between test methods. Check whether full string is visible when you select whole test class in the run pane instead of the single test method.
By the way, why would one print anything from automated test anyway? Asserts, mate!

Comment: @topr, Thanks for the response. I didn't put my actual tests here, which of course has asserts. I was unable to setup() the test because a file from the file system couldn't be read because it looked for it at /ath/o/ile.xml instead /path/to/file.xml.

Comment: Oh, so it's not only the matter of printing to the output. It's not enough details to provide more help, sorry. I haven't come across such problem myself. Have you tried maybe to launch tests outside of IDE? You can also try using Spock instead of plain jUnit. It's not a direct solution but maybe it will overcome your problem. Besides I think you might like Spock.